# Detect empty json body on POST

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out how to meet the demands of the consumers of my service.

In the POST body I send a json object. NONE of the fields are required. They are all optional. The consumer however wants an empty body {} or a bogus body { adaf: "32345" } to be detected and return an error.

I am using an ActionFilterAttribute currently to catch required fields but I am failing to figure out how to handle these two scenarios as they pass right by this line:

> var validationAttribute = attributeInstance as ValidationAttribute;

because they are optional and thus have NO ValidationAttribute

VALID POST body json is ONE of these two...either or...doesn't matter:

```
{
  amount: 123.45,
  age: 65
}
```

My api signature:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/....blah")]
[ValidateModelState]
public async Task<Resp> AgePost([FromBody]AgeMoney)
{ .... }
```

My ValidationFilter:

```
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Per https://blog.markvincze.com/how-to-validate-action-parameters-with-dataannotation-attributes/
        var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        if (descriptor != null)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in descriptor.MethodInfo.GetParameters())
            {
                object args = null;
                if (context.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(parameter.Name))
                {
                    args = context.ActionArguments[parameter.Name];
                }

                ValidateAttributes(parameter, args, context.ModelState);
            }
        }

        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new BadRequestException("The following fields from the request body failed model validation: " + string.Join(", ", context.ModelState.Keys));
        }
    }

    private void ValidateAttributes(ParameterInfo parameter, object args, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        foreach (var attributeData in parameter.CustomAttributes)
        {
            var attributeInstance = parameter.GetCustomAttribute(attributeData.AttributeType);

            var validationAttribute = attributeInstance as ValidationAttribute;
            if (validationAttribute != null)
            {
                var isValid = validationAttribute.IsValid(args);
                if (!isValid)
                {
                    modelState.AddModelError(parameter.Name, validationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(parameter.Name));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way using reflection. Feel free to comment / improve. Always eager to learn.

```
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
       //snipped for brevity. See OP for full implementation  
       IsAllNullOrEmpty(args);
       ValidateAttributes(parameter, args, context.ModelState);

    }
}




public void IsAllNullOrEmpty(object myObject)
{
   //Get the object so we don't have to keep calling reflection
   var obj = myObject.GetType();

  //Get a count of how many properties there are
  var propCount = obj.GetProperties().Count();

  var areAllNullOrEmpty = obj.GetProperties()
  .Select(pi => pi.GetValue(myObject))
  .Count(value => value == null);

  if (areAllNullOrEmpty == propCount)
  { throw new BadRequestException("The request body failed model validation."); }

}
```